# My flutter application is getting crashed when image is captured by camera using image_picker: ^0.6.7+14.How to fix this issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, camera, gallery, imagepicker

My flutter application is getting crashed when image is captured by camera using  image_picker: ^0.6.7+14.How to fix this issue.

I have used image cropping and compressing too in this code  where s there is no issue for Gallery Upload.

Please suggest me the sutable dependencies and import libraries so that my application never crash and works fine .

My code is as follows

```
 void getImageFile(ImageSource source) async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

    //Cropping the image

    File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
      statusBarColor: Colors.red,
      toolbarColor: Colors.red,
      toolbarTitle: "Crop Image",
      toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
    ),
      sourcePath: image.path,
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
      ],
      maxWidth: 800,
    );
    if (croppedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        image = croppedFile;
        _image = image;
        print('Image Path $_image');
        // print('Image Path $_image');

        isimage_selected = true;
        image_show_containervisible = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

and openImagePickercontext for picking Camera dn Gallery options(including code for firebase storage)

```
 void openImagePickerModal(BuildContext context) {
    final flatButtonColor = Theme
        .of(context)
        .primaryColor;
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: 180.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Visibility(
                  visible: visibilityFlag1,
                  child: Center(

                    child: FlatButton(

                     child: Text("Chose Image from Camera"),

                      onPressed: () async {

                       // _getImageFile(ImageSource.camera);
                          _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

                          FirebaseStorage fs = FirebaseStorage.instance;

                          StorageReference rootReference = fs.ref();
                          Random random = new Random();
                          int randomNumber = random.nextInt(1000);
                          final StorageReference pictureFolderRef = rootReference
                              .child("NewImages").child("Photo${randomNumber}");

                          pictureFolderRef
                              .putFile(_image)
                              .onComplete
                              .then((storageTask) async {
                            String link = await storageTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
                            print("Photo uploaded");
                            setState(() {

                              imageLink = link;
                            });
                          });
                        },
                        color: Colors.green,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                ),
                ),



                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Chose Image From Gallery"),
                  onPressed: () async {
                   // _getImageFile(ImageSource.gallery);
                  _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

                    FirebaseStorage fs = FirebaseStorage.instance;

                    StorageReference rootReference = fs.ref();
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(1000);
                    final StorageReference pictureFolderRef = rootReference
                        .child("NewImages").child("Image${randomNumber}");

                    pictureFolderRef
                        .putFile(_image)
                        .onComplete
                        .then((storageTask) async {
                      String link = await storageTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
                      print("Image uploaded");
                      setState(() {

                        imageLink = link;
                      });
                    });
                  },
                  color: Colors.green,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                ),


              ],
            ),
          );
        });
    //Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }


}
```

First after click  or capture  from camera or gallery I want to place the image in my circular avatar or place holder for image

```
  children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,

                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 100,
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xff476cfb),
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: new SizedBox(
                            width: 200.0,
                            height: 200.0,
                            child: (_image!=null)?Image.file(_image, fit: BoxFit.fill,):Image.network(imageLink, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                    ),


                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.camera,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          openImagePickerModal(context);
                          //uploadPic(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
```

Errors shown in the log are as folows
[Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6QZq.jpg)

```
my errors  when I capture image                                                                                              

    E/flutter (14972): 
E/flutter (18098): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'absolute' was called on null.
E/flutter (18098): Receiver: null
E/flutter (18098): Tried calling: absolute
E/flutter (18098): #0      _StorageFileUploadTask._platformStart (package:firebase_storage/src/upload_task.dart:135)
E/flutter (18098): #1      StorageUploadTask._start (package:firebase_storage/src/upload_task.dart:35)
E/flutter (18098): #2      StorageReference.putFile (package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart:65)
E/flutter (18098): #3      _EditProductState.openImagePickerModal.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:sqlite_crud_flutter/screens/edit_product.dart:845)
E/flutter (18098): #4      _EditProductState.openImagePickerModal.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:sqlite_crud_flutter/screens/edit_product.dart:830)
E/flutter (18098): #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992)
E/flutter (18098): #6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098)
E/flutter (18098): #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184)
E/flutter (18098): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524)
E/flutter (18098): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:301)
E/flutter (18098): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256)
E/flutter (18098): #11     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158)
E/flutter (18098): #12     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224)
E/flutter (18098): #13     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200)
E/flutter (18098): #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158)
E/flutter (18098): #15     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104)
E/flutter (18098): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88)
E/flutter (18098): #17     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206)
E/flutter (18098): #18     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100)
E/flutter (18098): #19     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005)
E/flutter (18098): #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267)
E/flutter (18098): #21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176)
E/flutter (18098):
```

Comment: Which error is shows after clicking image from camera !!!

Comment: Error log is not sufficient, pls share whole error with  call stack

Comment: I did'nt get what is call stack is debug log ?

Comment: Please sggest me a way with which my application never crashes  either by compressing method, lowering the memor or size of the image ,cropping or  any other method.URGENT

Comment: decreasing the memory size of the image

Comment: Do you have given the needed permissions to it?

Comment: yes in androidmanifest.xml already for camera and storage. and for cropping also                  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>     and   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>                              <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

Comment: Yes I have the permissions needed.

Comment: Yes please somebody help me fix my issue   with camera plugin  if possible.

Comment: Somebody please fix my issue